# get information from a form in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a new developer
I want to store the form information Which is located inside the partial view to my data base.
Can this be done like a regular view with a razor? There is no need to do anything special...?

Comment: Please provide some code snippet to better understand the problem, And what you have tried so far.

Comment: @zahra share your code by editing your question

Comment: I have an index page that I put in that a button ;by pressing it a modal opens that located in my partial view. inside the modal is a form.How I can save it's information?Is it similar to the form in the index view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything special zahra, just call your partial view in your razor view, by using form or ajax call, you can send the form data to mvc controller and from there you can store the data in your Database